# Spring Boot with multiple databases but without autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to develop a spring boot application which acts as a database rest api and for this I want to make the app as dynamic as possible.

For this I want to make "plugins" which 1. use their own database and entities 2. hold FlyWay migration scripts and 3. define their own Controllers

So far so good - but as I want to have multiple databases I tried to turn off all JAP related autoconfiguration classes but this leads to multiple unsatisfied dependencies when I tried to set up the DataSource/TransactionManager/EntityManager manually ... and no tutorial worked (mostly outdated).

Is there a full tutorial or example of how to set up multiple databases which are related to specific entities and flyway migrations?

And without specifying @Primary JPA beans?

**Update:**

Most tutorials bring me to the point where I need an `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder` which is normally auto-generated by Spring Boot Autoconfiguration but when I try to instantiate a custom one like in all examples I have found:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
    return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), new HashMap<>(), null);
}
```

I get a compilation error:

> 'EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' is abstract, cannot be instantiated

What is wrong with all the tutorials or what am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases. Instead of auto-configuration, for each database, you may create different configurations (@Configuration) and use those in ContextConfiguration.

Comment: @fiveelements yes I already tried this but I always run into missing beans which are not mentioned in the tutorial ... but I will try it again maybe I was missing something ...

Comment: I find you question interesting because sometimes all those spring-boot-starters are doing unexpected things behind the scene and it happens that you want to do things all by yourself. But I think that then you might find more information in `Spring 5` configuraiton information.